# WebRTC video call between logged in users

Tags: authorization, webrtc, identification

I have a web application with e.g 1...n users. User(s) logs in use application and logs out.
Now How to achieve if a logged in user say User "A" want to video chat with User "B"?
Does WebRTC shares a sessionId etc to identify which user is sending request and how this request is for specific set of users (Receivers would be only "B" User) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, WebRTC does not provide this kind of authorization. That's because WebRTC relies on an external signaling system.

This kind of authorization you must include it in your signaling system. E.g. if you're using websockets you can use the session from there to authorize, identify and route the message to the appropriate user. And that will depend of course on what platform/technology you're using on the server side.